# How to unite rows by same date?

Tags: sql

I have this table
[image: Table 1]

I want to create a query that will return data in the following format:
date (just a day), sms_number, etc...

So I want to unite rows from the 1st table by days and return statistics for it, for example amount of sms (rows) for one day (for example for 2020-07-07, time should not be taken into account).

How do I do this using SQL (provide an example)?

Comment: You will want to look into the `DATE()` function, `COUNT()` function, and `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: What `DBMS` you are using?

Comment: @Ahmed MariaDB (MySQL fork)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date_,'%Y-%m-%d') AS 
date_, count(date_) as sms_number from 
sms_logs 
group by DATE_FORMAT(date_,'%Y-%m-%d') 
order by date_ DESC
```

See a `MySQL` demo from [***db-fiddle***](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eDAQv7AhWkpm7Na3HkUq2P/1).

Comment: Thank you. I changed query a bit so it now satisfies me. Add it to your answer: `
    select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date_, count(date) as sms_number
    from sms_logs
    group by date_
    ORDER BY date_ DESC;` And I'll accept it

Comment: You are welcome. The answer has been updated, kindly check it.